# Playing cards without a check in Pathfinder

Tags: pathfinder-adventure

Somewhere in the Pathfinder ACG rule book, I remembered reading, that for each check, any player may use one card of each of the different card types, meaning only a single Spell card, Weapon card, Item card, etc.

I don't remember finding in the rules, if I am able to use cards when I am 'between checks'.

For example, if I have 2 Cure cards in my hand, can I use both cards, BEFORE my first free exploration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes playing both cards outside of an encounter are allowed. From the Pathfinder Skull and Shackles rulebook (and probably the others as well as the rule hasn't changed) on page 9:

> **Playing Cards**
>
> Anyone can play a card whenever the card allows it. Playing a card
>   means using a power on that card by revealing, displaying, discarding,
>   recharging, burying, or banishing that card or by performing another
>   action specified by that card.